# Why is this if statement True

Tags: python, if-statement

`par_list` is initiated in some code prior to this.  For the section I am testing it on, `"calendar"` does not appear. Why then does it evaluate the if statement as `True`?

```
while cake:
    print "Length of par_list = ", len(par_lst)

    for rows in par_lst:
        if "calendar" or "Calendar" in rows:
            print "you shouldn't be here"
            writer.writerow(rows)
```

Comment: Which "this if"??? There are three if-statements? Reduce your code to a reasonable test case.

Answer (score 10):

That's because your code should be this:

```
if "calendar" in rows or "Calendar" in rows:
```

In Python, non-empty strings always evaluate to `True`.  Furthermore, your current code is basically the same as this:

```
if ("calendar") or ("Calendar" in rows):
```

This means that this condition will always return `True` because `"calendar"` will always be `True`.  In fact, it will never even get to the `("Calendar" in rows)` part.

As a demonstration, consider this:

```
>>> bool("calendar" or "Calendar" in rows)
True
>>>
```

Notice how, even though I haven't even defined `rows`, I don't get a `NameError`.  Instead, the code returns `True`.  That's because, as I said above, it never even gets to the `"Calendar" in rows` part.  In fact, all it does is evaluate `"calendar"` which, being a non-empty string, returns `True`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if "calendar" or "Calendar" in rows:
```

This is always true. `"calendar"` being a non-zero-length string, it is true, and that `or`'d with `"Calendar" in rows` is always true. In fact, `"Calendar" in rows` is never even evaluated because `"calendar"` is true.

You want:

```
if "calendar" in rows or "Calendar" in rows:
```

This isn't the most efficient since it will actually search `rows` twice. To search it only once, try:

```
if (row.lower() = "calendar" for row in rows):
```

However, this may not actually be any faster than searching the rows twice: first because it's an explicit loop, second because it's lowercasing each row before testing it.  It does have the advantage of matching *any* case, not just "calendar" or "Calendar" but also "CALENDAR" or "CALenDAR" or whatever.

Now, I get the feeling that this still may not be what you want. Unless one of the rows is *exactly* the string `"calendar"` (in any case), this is always going to be false. For example, if you have read the list from a file, it may contain line endings, which will keep this test from matching. Or there may be other text in the string and you just want to test whether each row *contains* that word.  In this case, write:

```
if any("calendar" in row.lower() for row in rows):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if "calendar" or "Calendar" in rows:
```

is equivalent to

```
if "calendar" or ("Calendar" in rows):
```

Since `"calendar"` is truthful, the condition passes.